# Seq.iter vs for - what difference?

Tags: f#

I can do

```
for event in linq.Deltas do
```

or I can do

```
linq.Deltas |> Seq.iter(fun event ->
```

So I'm not sure if that is the same. If that is not the same I want to know the difference. I don't know what to use: `iter` or `for`.

**added** - so if that is the matter of choice I prefer to use `iter` on a top level and `for` is for closures

**added some later** - looking like `iter` is `map` + `ignore` - it's the way to run from using imperative ignore word. So it's looking like functional way ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can modify mutable variables from the body of a `for` loop. You can't do that from a closure, which implies you can't do that using `iter`. (Note: I'm talking about mutable variables declared outside of the `for` / `iter`. Local mutable variables are accessible.)

Considering that the point of `iter` is to perform some side effect, the difference can be important.

I personally seldom use `iter`, as I find `for` to be clearer.

Answer (score 19):

As others mentioned, there are some differences (`iter` supports non-generic `IEnumerator` and you can mutate `mutable` values in `for`). These are sometimes important differences, but most of the times you can freely choose which one to use.

I generally prefer `for` (if there is a language construct, why not use it?). The cases where `iter` looks nicer are when you have a function that you need to call (e.g. using partial application):

```
// I would write this:
strings |> Seq.iter (printfn "%c")

// instead of:
for s in strings do printfn "%c" s
```

Similarly, using `iter` is nicer if you use it at the end of some processing pipeline:

```
// I would write this:
inputs |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x > 0)
       |> Seq.iter (fun x -> foo x)

// instead of:
let filtered = inputs |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x > 0)
for x in filtered do foo x
```

Answer (score 2):

For most of the situations, they are the same. I would prefer the first use. It looks clear to me.

The difference is that `for in` loop support `IEnumerable` objects, while Seq.iter requires that your collection (`linq.deltas`) is `IEnumerable<T>`.

E.g. `MatchCollection` class in .net regular expression inherits `IEnumerable` not `IEnumerable<T>`, you cannot use `Seq.map` or `Seq.iter` directly on it. But you can use `for in` loop.

Comment: You can still do something like seq{ for x in matchCollection ->x}

Comment: Or `matchColl |> seq.cast<Match> |> Seq.iter`

Answer (score 1):

It is the style of programming. Imperative vs using functional programming. Keep in mind that F# is not a pure functional programming language.

Generally, use Seq.Iter if it is a part of some large pipeline processing, as that makes it much more clearer, but for ordinary case I think the imperative way is clearer. Sometime it is a personal preference, sometimes it is other issues like performance.

Answer (score 0):

`for` in F# is a form of [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#F.23) - bread and butter of functional programming while `Seq.iter` is a 'for side-effects only' imperative construct - not a sign of a functional code. Here what you can do with `for`:

```
let pairsTo n = seq {
    for i in [1..n] do
        for j in [i..n] do
             if j%i <> 0 then yield (i,j) }

printf "%A" (pairsTo 10 |> Seq.toList)
```

Comment: There are two different `for` in F# - one is inside list comprehensions (as you say) and the other is imperative `for` which is quite similar to `Seq.iter`.