# F# changing state made of objects

Tags: f#, pass-by-reference, immutability, record, mutable

I have a simulator that keeps some state as a record with two members: one object of Class1, and a sequence of objects of Class2.

When the simulation runs, input is read and, depending on the input, some methods of those objects are called. Such method change their internal state.

I am learning F# and I understand the importance of immutable data. However, given the complexity of such state (much more than exposed here), I think that having such objects with internal mutable state is not a big deal. At least it is hidden.

The problem is, however, another one. And it's probably simple.

In between iterations I lose changes to "one" and "many" objects!

I guess InvokeMethodOn (obviously simplified) takes a copy of those objects.

I realize I need some kind of references here but... I am a bit lost here... State should have ref members? InvokeMethodOn should pass by ref? All of them? And what about the "many" sequence?

**EDIT :** There could be millions of "many" objects. Each of them has 1 or 2 KB of state (which for now is just kept in a blob of bytes).

**EDIT :** Changing "many" to be an array (and using Array.iter as suggested) fixed the issue. Thanks to everybody!

```
type State = {
    one : Class1
    many : Class2 seq
}

type Simulator() = class
    member x.run(state : State) =
        // ....
        while ...
            let input = ReadInput
            if someFuncOf(input)
                then InvokeMethodOn(state.one, input)
                else Seq.iter (fun x -> InvokeMethodOn(x, input)) state.many                

    member x.InvokeMethodOn obj input =
         obj.ChangeInternalState input
```

Comment: Possibly something is wrong with your `ChangeInternalState`, With `seq` you need to be careful as `seqs` are lazy - probably best to use an array/list instead

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726566/seq-iter-vs-for-what-difference Please refer Joh's answer. Simply put, a for loop would be better here.

Comment: Is it correct that `obj.ChangeInternalState` only changes something within `Class2`, e.g. `Class2.mutableValue`? Or your goal is to mutate `State.many` so it pointed to a different sequence of `Class2` objects?

Comment: First assumption is correct: obj.ChangeInternalState only changes internal attributes. Nowhere in the code I change "one" or "many".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Class1 and Class2 contain mutable state that you change, I don't see a reason why such change would be discarded at each iteration, unless you are recreating new copies of Class1 somehow.

If I try to script a similar thing than what is presented, it runs fines.
It would be interesting to know how your code diverge from this to find where we are missing something.

```
type Class1 = { mutable label : string}
type Container = { one : Class1; many : Class1 seq}

let a = { label = "a" }
let bs = [ { label = "b1" } ; { label = "b2" }]

let cont = { one =a ; many = bs}
printfn  "%A" cont.one.label

cont.one.label <- "changed a"
cont.many |> Seq.iter (fun x -> x.label <- "changed b")
printfn  "%A" cont

cont.one.label <- "changed again a"
printfn  "%A" cont
```

Note that in F# ref are really just a hidden representation of 'mutable content'

```
type 'a ref = { mutable contents : 'a }
```

You might want to read this page about [mutation in FSharp](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Data)
There is little magic to it and it should clarify many things.

Also one thing to note regarding mutable data is that array are mutable by default : no need to re-declare them mutable.

Comment: The only difference I see with my code is that you change mutable fields in "one" and "many" directly, while I call methods in those objects to change their internal mutable fields.

Answer (score 2):

> In between iterations I lose changes to "one" and "many" objects!
>
> I guess InvokeMethodOn (obviously simplified) takes a copy of those objects.

You guessed in wrong; `InvokeMethodOn` only modifies current states of `Class1` or `Class2`. Let's say you have a `State` record for each iteration. Because you didn't create new `Class1` and `Class2` instances anywhere, these records all point to the same class instances and are all modified in the same way in each iteration.

> I think that having such objects with internal mutable state is not a big deal. At least it is hidden.

It is a big deal. Your *hidden* states are leaked and cause wrong behaviors. I believe you are worrying about performance so that you want to mutate `Class1` and `Class2`'s states. I don't know how pass by reference could help you. An easy way to fix is to write

```
member x.InvokeMethodOn obj input =
         obj.CreateNewInstanceWith input
```

and change `while` to some sort of `Seq.fold` where you return new `State` by calling `InvokeMethodOn` on fields.

I think it would be better if you declare `Class1` and `Class2` as records and use `with` block: `{class1 with value = newValue}`. You always can change records to have mutable fields later if you need to do performance optimization. Furthermore, don't declare `seq` as a record field, it destroys *structural equality* on records.

Comment: You guessed right pad, I am worrying about performance. There are millions of "many" objects at time, each carrying several KB of state. And most of the times I need to modify just a few bytes of its state.
I thought that maybe the mutable path was the best.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you should ensure correctness first. Start with an immutable version so that you can easily reason about. Optimize performance from the correct version would be much easier.